# PHP is_embed error showing up

Tags: php, errors

I can't seem to find what's causing the error to show up when I enabled the debug mode on my WordPress website that is installed locally.

> Notice: is_embed was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hostingfacts/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4139

Is this some plugin issue?

P.S. I'm using MAMP

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is not because debug mode, it seems that the hook you're using is being called before the $wp_query is set.

what you can do is put inside your function

```
function your_error_function(){
        global $wp_query;
        if(! isset( $wp_query )){
          return 
        }
    ...rest of my code
}
```

or change the hook you're using to another that is called later, something like 'loop_start' should do.